# How to pass lightning-input-address field value to actual address field in LWC record edit form save?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, address

I have created lightning-record-edit form component to create a new record. I have added code to display Input address field in the component.

Below is the code that I have used:

**LWC HTML:**

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name={sfdcObjectApiName} record-type-id={recTypeId} onsuccess={handleSuccess}
        onerror={handleError} density="comfy">
        <lightning-messages if:false={closeError}></lightning-messages>
        <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open active-section-name={activeSection}>
            <template class="slds-grid slds-gutters" for:each={fields_per_section} for:item="accordion_item">
                <div class="slds-grid" key={accordion_item.label}>
                    <div>
                        <lightning-icon icon-name={accordion_item.iconname} size="xx-small">
                        </lightning-icon>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-col" key={accordion_item.label}>
                        <lightning-accordion-section key={accordion_item.label} name={accordion_item.label}
                            label={accordion_item.label} if:false={accordion_item.addressSection}>
                            <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
                                <lightning-layout-item size="12" small-device-size="12" medium-device-size="6"
                                    large-device-size="6" for:each={accordion_item.fields}
                                    for:item="fieldFromSubsection" key={fieldFromSubsection}>
                                    <lightning-input-field key={fieldFromSubsection} field-name={fieldFromSubsection}
                                        id={fieldFromSubsection}>
                                    </lightning-input-field>
                                </lightning-layout-item>
                            </lightning-layout>
                        </lightning-accordion-section>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="slds-col" key={accordion_item.label} if:true={accordion_item.addressSection}>
                        <lightning-accordion-section key={accordion_item.label} name={accordion_item.label}
                            label={accordion_item.label}>
                            <lightning-layout multiple-rows>
                                <lightning-input-address address-label="Address" country-label="Country" street-label="Street"
                                        city-label="City" postal-code-label="Zip/ Postal Code" province-label="State/ Province"
                                        street={addressAddress.Street} city={addressAddress.City} province={addressAddress.State} 
                                        postal-code={addressAddress.PostalCode} country={addressAddress.Country}
                                        field-level-help="Select Address" country-options={countryOptions} province-options={stateOptions} onchange={addressInputChange}
                                        show-address-lookup>
                                    </lightning-input-address>
                            </lightning-layout>
                        </lightning-accordion-section>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </template>
        </lightning-accordion>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

**LWC JS:**

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    api,
    track
} from 'lwc';
import getFieldsFromFieldSet from '@salesforce/apex/FieldSet.getFieldsFromFieldSet';
import getCountry from '@salesforce/apex/FieldSet.getCountry';
import getState from '@salesforce/apex/FieldSet.getState';
import {
    showToast
} from 'c/ToastMessageUtil'; //Display Toast Message from generic component
import LeadRecordSuccess from '@salesforce/label/c.LeadRecordSuccess';
import LeadPhoneCountryMsg from '@salesforce/label/c.LeadPhoneCountryMsg';
import LeadPhoneMsg from '@salesforce/label/c.LeadPhoneMsg';
import LeadPhoneDigitMsg from '@salesforce/label/c.LeadPhoneDigitMsg';
export default class NewLeadFieldSet extends LightningElement {
    label = {
        LeadRecordSuccess,
        LeadPhoneCountryMsg,
        LeadPhoneMsg,
        LeadPhoneDigitMsg
    };
    @api recTypeId;
    inputLeadInfoFieldAPIs = [];
    inputAddressFieldAPIs = [];
    inputOtherFieldAPIs = [];
    renderCall = false;
    //get its value from container component through attributes
    @api sfdcObjectApiName; //Lead
    @api fieldSetName; //
    section1 = false;
    section2 = false;
    section3 = false;
    phoneCodeMap = new Map();
    isPhoneCodeNotBlank = true;
    showSpinner;
    spinnerVariant;
    spinnerMessage;
    @track activeSection = [];
    @track fields_per_section = [];
    _isNaN=false;
    isDigitLengthInvalid = false;
    closeError = false;_timeout;
    addressAddress = {
        Street: '',
        City: '',
        State: '',
        Postal: '',
        Country: ''
    }
    addressSection =false;
    @track data1 = [];
    @track data2 = [];
    fields;
    
    get countryOptions() {
        return this.data1;
    }
    get stateOptions() {
        return this.data2;
    }
    
    //load the record edit form with fields from fieldset.
    connectedCallback() {
        let objectApiName = this.sfdcObjectApiName;
        let fieldSetName = this.fieldSetName;
        //Get Country Details from Standard State and Country Picklist 
         getCountry().then(result=>{
            //let data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
            let lstOption = [];
            for (const property in result) {
                lstOption.push({value: result[property],label: property
                });
              }
            this.data1 = lstOption;
        })
        
        //Get Country Details from Standard State and Country Picklist 
        
        getState().then(result=>{
            let lstOption1 = [];
            for (const property in result) {
                lstOption1.push({value: result[property],label: property
                });
              }
            this.data2 = lstOption1;
        })
        //make an implicit call to fetch fields from database
        getFieldsFromFieldSet({
                strObjectApiName: objectApiName,
                strfieldSetName: fieldSetName
            })
            .then(data => {
                let items = []; //local array to hold the field api
                let listOfLeadInfoFields;
                let listOfAddressFields;
                let listOfOtherFields;
                //get the entire map
                let objStr = JSON.parse(data);
                for (let key in objStr) {
                    items = [];
                    listOfLeadInfoFields = JSON.parse(objStr[key]);
                    listOfLeadInfoFields.map(element => items.push(element.fieldPath));
                    this.inputLeadInfoFieldAPIs = items;
                    this.fields_per_section = [
                        ...this.fields_per_section,
                        {
                            "label": key.split(';')[0],
                            "fields": this.inputLeadInfoFieldAPIs,
                            "iconname": key.split(';')[1]
                        }
                    ]
                }
                this.activeSection = this.fields_per_section[0].label;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                console.log('error', error);
            })
    }

    renderedCallback() {
        if (!this.renderCall) {
            this.renderCall = true;
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new CustomEvent('cmploaded')
            );
        }
        if (this.closeError) {
            this.closeError = false;
        }
    }
    
    addressInputChange(event) {
        console.log('addressInputChange:');
        this.addressAddress.Street = event.target.street;
        this.addressAddress.City =  event.target.city;
        this.addressAddress.State = event.target.province;
        this.addressAddress.Country = event.target.country;
        this.addressAddress.PostalCode = event.target.postalCode;
        window.clearTimeout(this._timeout);
        this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
           // this.handleAddressChange();
        }, 500);
        
    }

    //This method submits the record edit form and getting called from another container component
    @api
    handleSubmit() {
    
    **let inpuAddresstFields;
             
            if(this.addressAddress != undefined){
            //Not able to pass  field value to actual address before submitting record
            const inpuAddresstFields = this.template.querySelectorAll('lightning-input-address');
            inpuAddresstFields.forEach(field => {
               field.cityLabel  =  this.addressAddress.City;
               field.provinceLabel  = this.addressAddress.State;
               field.countryLabel  =  this.addressAddress.Country;
               field.postalCodeLabel   = this.addressAddress.PostalCode;
               field.streetLabel  = this.addressAddress.Street;
            });
           
        }**
        let isValidate = this.validateFields();
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('validatefields', {
                detail: {
                    check: isValidate
                }
            })
        );
        if (isValidate) {
            //Submitting Records.
            **this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(inpuAddresstFields);**
        } 
        

    }

    validateFields() {
        return [...this.template.querySelectorAll("lightning-input-field")].reduce((validSoFar, field) => {
           
            //return (field.reportValidity() && this.isPhoneCodeNotBlank & !this._isNaN && !this.isDigitLengthInvalid);
            return (validSoFar && field.reportValidity() );
        }, true);
    }

    //This event handler fires on post submit and displays success and propagate event to container
    handleSuccess(event) {
        this.leadName = (this.leadFirstName ===undefined || this.leadFirstName ===null || this.leadFirstName ==='' ) ? this.leadLastName : this.leadFirstName + ' '+this.leadLastName;
        this.dispatchEvent(
            showToast('success', 'dismissable', '', this.label.LeadRecordSuccess.replace('{leadName}',`"${this.leadName}"`))
        );
        //raise event to parent to handle this and to close the popup, specify bubbles=true
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('postsuccess', {
                detail: event.detail.id
            })
        );
    }
    handleError(event) {
        console.log("handleError event");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail.detail));
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('validatefields', {
                detail: {
                    check: false
                }
            })
        );
        window.clearTimeout(this._timeout);
        this._timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            this.closeError = true;
        }, 10000);
    }
}
```

Problem 1 :
**strong text**
In the above code, I am getting State and Country Picklist value but I could not show State belongs to Selected Country(Dependencies Missing). Is there way to show State dependencies based on Country?

**Problem 2:** In the above code, I am not able to pass Input address field value to actual address on Lead record so when record gets created, it does not map input-address value to actual field. Since I am using Custom Submit button from another form due to which I could not use onsubmit event on this form.

Can someone please help what is wrong in above code?